# FlaskForm url_for based on form input

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-restful

I am trying to get input on a form as shown here:

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-signin" method="GET" action="{{url_for('getstonks', ticker='ticker')}}">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">INPUT TICKER ID</h2>
    <br>
    <!-- {{ form.csrf_token }} -->
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.ticker) }}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">GET</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Below is my InputForm class

```py
class InputForm(FlaskForm):
    ticker = StringField(label="Ticker", validators=[validators.DataRequired()])
```

And here is my API flask_restful endpoint

```py
api.add_resource(GetStonks, "/api/v1/stocks/<string:ticker>")
```

Ideally I would take the input, given to the form and then the form action would send you to that URL with the input appended to the end.  e.g. if you put "COIN" into the form and you would be routed to my endpoint with the following url: `/api/v1/stocks/COIN`

I have tried multiple arguments in my

```py
action="{{url_for('getstonks', ticker='ticker')}}">
```

And it seems like the WHOLE form is being passed instead of just input value within the form ?

Here is an example of the behavior right now in my codes current state:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/stocks/%3Cinput%20id%3D%22ticker%22%20name%3D%22ticker%22%20required%20type%3D%22text%22%20value%3D%22%22%3E?ticker=AMZN`

I greatly appreciate any guidance, this has been stumping me for a couple days.

Comment: As a workaround just use the form to send the ticket to a static endpoint as a POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the root cause was, however, instead of using `flask_restul` I built a "regular" flask route:

```py
@app.route("/api/v1/stocks/")
def get_stocks():

    TICKER = request.args.get('ticker')
```

and then used `TICKER = request.args.get('ticker')` to pass into my url.  From there my form action looked as follows:

```html
  <form class="form-signin" method="get" action="{{url_for('get_stocks')}}">
```

Hope this helps someone, the `flask_restful` approach might have been super superfluous in my case.